# Backloader uploader not working online

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, backload

I'm using `Backload Jquery` File Upload to upload images. It is working fine in offline.

After deployment on server, the image does't get uploaded and it also does't show any error. Please help me out with this problem.